# 14.04.2 ubuntu installation using hyper-v VM

Tags: live-usb, hyper-v

i am new to Ubuntu.

i tried installing 14.04.2 using dual boot, i was able to install Ubuntu, but had issues with my win8.1 boot, so i went back to win8.1 only (that uninstalled ubuntu though)

now i started a VM using hyper-v and able to start ubuntu without installing. my question is, how to install ubuntu on my VM using USB?

Thanks!

Comment: followed one of the videos, gen1 is running on hyper-v. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a USB drive easily from a Hyper-V machine.  The way I handle this is to create a folder on my windows system called "OS".  I put the .iso file for my Ubuntu installation into this folder.  Then when you create your Hyper-V virtual machine you can specify a Vitural DVD which gives you access to the Windows OS folder you created.  Browse to it and select it.  Continue on with your installation and when it starts up the .iso will be run and your OS install will start.

Here is my step-by-step I created that I follow.

**In Hyper-V Manager after settup up Virtual Machine**

- [X]Disable Secure Boot for LINUX Ubuntu.  Settings>Firmware>make sure
  Enable Secure Boot is NOT checked
- [X]Add DVD and point to .iso for OS Install.  settings>SCSI
  Controller>DVD Drive>Image File>Browse
- [X]Select Image file (.iso), browse your computer to find the ubuntu
  server .iso (ubuntu-15.04-server-amd64.iso) file and click apply
- [X]Move the DVD drive up to the top of the list so it boots first. Firmware>right side, Move Up in boot order.  Now click ok.
- [X]Right click the new Virtual Machine Name and click start
- [X]Right-click again on the newly created VM and click Connect.
- [X]Once connected, the system will commence with the installation of Virtual Machine OS on
  the newly created virtual instance.
- [X]When the installer launches continue with your installation as you would any OS install.